# PHP doesnt show DIV / Contactform

Tags: php, forms, html, echo, contacts

This is the working code of mine, without the newest uggestions of Boynux. Now i will try to combine both and maybe to get red div boxes if a error occures. Thanks to all for your help, i think now im very close to the result i was thinking about.

PHP

```
<section id="main-content">

<div class="text-intro"><h2>KONTAKT</h2></div>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['sendMessage'])) {
$to = "info@test.com";
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'E-mail: '.$email."\n";
$from = 'Message: '.$message;
$body_message = "Question";

echo "<div id=\"submitmessage\">Thank you.</div>"; 
mail($to, $body, $from);
} else {
echo "Please check you data.";
}
?>

<div class="columns features">
<br />
<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="contact-form" class="contact-form">
<textarea id='message' maxlength='10000' name='message' placeholder='Hello...'>   
</textarea>
<div class='crayonico'></div>
<input class='text-input' id='senderEmail' maxlength='50' name='email'   
placeholder='E-Mail' type='email'>
<div class='emailico'></div>
<input class='btn btn-input' id='sendMessage' name='sendMessage' type='submit'  
value='SEND'>
</form>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>
```

HTML

```
<section id="home-head" class="contact">     
<h1></h1>
</section>

<section id="main-content">

<div class="text-intro"><h2>CONTACT</h2></div>

<div class="columns features">
<br />
<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="contact-form" class="contact-form">
<textarea id='message' maxlength='10000' name='message' placeholder='HEllo...'>   
</textarea>
<div class='crayonico'></div>
<input class='text-input' id='senderEmail' maxlength='50' name='email' 
placeholder='E-Mail' type='email'>
<div class='emailico'></div>
<input class='btn btn-input' id='sendMessage' name='sendMessage' type='submit'  
value='SEND'>
</form>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is not like ASP.NET or simillar frame works in which template and code are separated. IF you are not considering other frameworks like Symfony or CakePHP you need to print the complete HTML ouput to browser:

```
<?php
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_message = $_POST['message'];
$mail_to = 'email@email.de ';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;
$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Email result</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div>
<?php
    if ($mail_status){
        echo "Thanks for your mail...";
    }else{
        echo "Please correct your data.";
    }
?>
         </div>
    </body>
```

And for form validation you can use javasctipt:

```
<div id="main-content">
    <div class="text-intro"><h2>CONTACT</h2></div>
    <div id="thanks"></div>
    <div class="columns features">
    <br />
    <form action="contact.php" method="post" id="contact-form" class="contact-form"  onsubmit="return validate ()>
        <textarea id='message' maxlength='10000' name='message' placeholder='Hello...'> </textarea>
        <div class='crayonico'></div>
        <input class='text-input' id='senderEmail' maxlength='50' name='email' placeholder='E-Mail' type='email'>
        <div class='emailico'></div>
        <input class='btn btn-input' id='sendMessage' name='sendMessage' type='submit' value='SEND'">
    </form>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>
<script language="javascript">
function validate()
{
    // for example I check sender email
    if ( document.getElementById ( 'senderEmail' ).value.length > 0 )
        return true;
    else
        alert ( "Sender address required" );
        return false;
}
</script>
```

But keep in mind that validation using javascript is not enough as user can simply bypass this checking os consider checking everything again in PHP code.

OK, here is a complete sample, but please note that this is not well written and complete code this is just a sample for start:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Email result</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php

// function to compose email
function sendMail ( $sender, $message ) {
    $mail_to = 'email@email.de ';
    $subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;
    $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
    $body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;
    $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";
    return  mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
}

// check if form submited?
if ( isset ($_POST['sendMessage']) ) {
    $email = trim ($_POST['email']);
    $message = trim ($_POST['message']);

    if ($email == null || strlen ($email) == 0 ) {
        $alert = "Sender address required.";
    } else if ( $message == null || strlen ($message) == 0 ) {
        $alert = "Empty messages is not allowed.";
    } else if ( sendMail ( $email, $message ) ) {
        $alert = "Thanks for your mail...";
    } else {
            $alert = "Please correct your data.";
    }
}
?>
<?php if ( isset ($alert) ): ?>
         <div style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'><?php echo $alert ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
        <div id="main-content">
            <div class="text-intro"><h2>CONTACT</h2></div>
            <div id="thanks"></div>
            <div class="columns features">
            <br />
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" id="contact-form" class="contact-form"  onsubmit="return validate ()">
                <textarea id='message' maxlength='10000' name='message' placeholder='Hello...'></textarea>
                <div class='crayonico'></div>
                <input class='text-input' id='senderEmail' maxlength='50' name='email' placeholder='E-Mail' type='email'>
                <div class='emailico'></div>
                <input class='btn btn-input' id='sendMessage' name='sendMessage' type='submit' value='SEND'>
            </form>
            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>
        <script language="javascript">
        function validate()
        {
            // for example I check sender email
            if ( document.getElementById ( 'senderEmail' ).value.length > 0 )
                return true;
            else
                alert ( "Sender address required" );
                return false;
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also to make javascript easier you could use jQuery or similar libraries also.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work, i thought if there isn't more than one letter into the email field, the java reacts...isn't?

Comment: which part not working? javascript? Actually I did not tested the code and just write it on the fly. I'll check it and post the update.

Comment: Thx, Okay i think it works but my fault was / is if you never write into the field the script doesn't react. But this is propably tweeky in programming.

Comment: Okay thanks, this works perfect. This is also the same point like Rogers version i think, because if i change the alert to $message, to echo the text in a div inside html i only get a blank page, so the transfer from php to div box is interrupted. The solution with alert, like in your example indeed works. The message solution is obviously nicer...:/ But thanks until then.

Comment: I'm happy this solved your problem. so you can mark it as answer.

Comment: Right, thanks again. How to echo it out into a div like Rogers last line, you can follow? So we had found both solutions :)

Comment: PHP result or JS result? which one you need to put in DIV?

Comment: It doesnt matter if php or js. I need Thank you in a Div Box above my form in the html file. but the php one "<div class="message_area"><?php echo $message;?></div>" doent work, because i get a white page :/

Comment: thats right. I now outside in a few hours I'll  be home and post complete solution for you.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! Meanwhile I tried tweeking with your first code and i also got it working with the div, if you want to see see the above the update. Now with this code I think i can combine it and maybe i will try to get red divs if an error occurs. BUT thank you very much for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

```
<section id="main-content">
<div class="text-intro"><h2>CONTACT</h2></div>
<div id="thanks"></div>
<div class="columns features">
<br />
<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="contact-form" class="contact-form">
<textarea id='message' maxlength='10000' name='message' placeholder='Hello...'>       </textarea>
<div class='crayonico'></div>
<input class='text-input' id='senderEmail' maxlength='50' name='email' placeholder='E- Mail' type='email'>
<div class='emailico'></div>
<input class='btn btn-input' id='sendMessage' name='sendMessage' type='submit' value='SEND'>
</form>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>

<script>

 if($("#senderEmail").val()==''){
  // alert the message
  return false;
 }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Validation you can use jQuery like

```
    $("#sendMessage").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("#senderEmail").val()=="") {
     alert('Email Blank');
     return false;
    } else {
     return true;
    }
  });
```

For the Message To display in a div using PHP

```
if ($mail_status){
$message = "Thanks for your mail...";
}else{
$message = "Please correct your data.";
}
```

Now you can `echo` out the `$message` in any div you wish

```
<div class="message_area"><?php echo $message;?></div>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<section id="main-content">

<div class="text-intro"><h2>KONTAKT</h2></div>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['sendMessage'])) {
$to = "info@test.com";
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'E-mail: '.$email."\n";
$from = 'Message: '.$message;
$body_message = "Question";

echo "<div id=\"submitmessage\">Thank you.</div>"; 
mail($to, $body, $from);
} else {
$message = "Please check you data.";
}
?>

<div class="columns features">
<br />
<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="contact-form" class="contact-form">
<textarea id='message' maxlength='10000' name='message' placeholder='Hello...'>   
</textarea>
<div class='crayonico'></div>
<input class='text-input' id='senderEmail' maxlength='50' name='email'   
placeholder='E-Mail' type='email'>
<div class='emailico'></div>
<input class='btn btn-input' id='sendMessage' name='sendMessage' type='submit'  
value='SEND'>
</form>
<div class="message_div">
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['sendMessage'])) {
            if(isset($message)) {
                echo $message;
            }   
        }
    ?>
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is this for echo correct?  <?php echo "<div id=''></div>"; ?>

Comment: Yes. Its correct; but you can simply have the div made in html and put the `$message` in that div. See the updated answer

Comment: Thanks for reply but if i press the send button i get a blank page. But i got it that the echo will showed in the div of the actual page not an new one?

Comment: Mainly it works but so that the div is shown in the php file not in the html. So you can use the form only once time because you are actual not in the html file. This is not so urgent because it works, but maybe it is possible to tweak it. Furthermore only if you click in the email field the validation works, if you never click into you could send the form without this data...thanks

Comment: Share the link or your code what you have tried and I will help you out

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Not exactly - in your updates code the div is into the php file, right? This works perfect with Thank you. But now if the form was sent, the actual page in the browser is the php. The question is, is it possible that the div with thank is in the html file not in the php? But if it is too complicated it is not so necessary. More important would be that it is impossbible to send the form without writing at least 1 letter in each field. Thanks so much :)

Comment: Okay. For that you need jQuery to use. That will help you get the thing you want.